# Netbeans dealing with Spring boot, JSP page can't recognize spring security tablib

Tags: netbeans-8

Problem is Netbeans fail to recognize the spring security tag, but it working well if deploy it, the IDE show me:

> "Unable to load tag handler class 'org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthenticationTag' for tag 'sec:authorize"

I'm using Netbeans 8.2, spring boot 1.4.3.RELEASE, and added below maven dependency into POM:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

JSP page added

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec"%>
```

Able to run all related spring security tag in JSP page:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Login</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

Please guide me solve IDE false negative issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't do anything, for those who using Netbean 8.2, this is a bug.

Check out here:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205304